# Browser compatibility issues Javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, compatibility

I got the following  Javascript code that works properly in Mozilla Firefox but it doesn't in Google Chrome. Any ideea why it will do that? 
totalBMI in Chrome even if the value is 45(checking all the last buttons will give you the value 45 which is bigger then 26 so the result should be setting the hRisk div to `display:-inline` instead of `display:none`, as the function `changeCss()` does.)  it still consider it to be 0, cause it displays the low risk message. In Firefox, it always displays the right answer.

Javascript code :

```
function CalculateValue()  {
var age = +getAgeValue('age'),
    bmi = +getBmiValue('bmi'),
    fami = +getFamValue('fam'),
    diet = +getDietValue('diet'),
    totalBMI = age + bmi + fami + diet;
    totalBMI = parseFloat(totalBMI); 
    alert(totalBMI);
if (totalBMI > 26) {
    function changeCSS() {           
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        var hMessage = document.getElementById("hRisk");
        hMessage.style.display = 'inline';
        /*var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        var newSpanText = document.createTextNode("Your main factors risk are "  );
        newSpan.appendChild(newSpanText);
        var pElem = document.getElementById("space");
        pElem.appendChild(newSpan); */
        }
    } 
    changeCSS();

} else if (totalBMI > 16 ) {
    function changeCSS() {           
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        var mMessage = document.getElementById("mRisk");
        mMessage.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    } 
    changeCSS();
} else {
    function changeCSS() {           
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        var lMessage = document.getElementById("lRisk");
        lMessage.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    } 
    changeCSS();
}
}



function getAgeValue()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('age').length; i++)
{
    if (document.getElementsByName('age')[i].checked)
    {
        return document.getElementsByName('age')[i].value;
    }
}
}

function getBmiValue()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('bmi').length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].value;
        }
    }
}    


function getFamValue()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('fam').length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName('fam')[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName('fam')[i].value;
        }
    }   
}

function getDietValue()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('diet').length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName('diet')[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName('diet')[i].value;
        }
    }     
}
```

HTML code:

```
<script src="jsbmi4.js"></script>
<title>Java</title>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="process.php" id="radioForm">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label for="age" class="lClass"> <span class="span1"> How old are you?     </span>
                <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="0">0-25
                <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="5">26-40
                <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="8">41-60
                <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="10">60+
                </label> 
            </div>
        <div>   
            <label for="bmi"> <span class="span1"> What is your BMI? </span>
                <input type="radio" id="bmi1" name="bmi" value="0">0-25
                <input type="radio" id="bmi1" name="bmi" value="0">26-30
                <input type="radio" id="bmi1" name="bmi" value="9">31-35
                <input type="radio" id="bmi1" name="bmi" value="10">35+
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>   
            <label for="fam"> <span class="span1"> Does anybody in your family have diabetes? </span>
                <input type="radio" id="fam1" name="fam" value="0">No
                <input type="radio" id="fam1" name="fam" value="7">Grandparent
                <input type="radio" id="fam1" name="fam" value="15">Sibling
                <input type="radio" id="fam1" name="fam" value="15">Parent
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>   
            <label for="diet"> <span class="span1"> How would you describe your diet? </span>
                <input type="radio" id="diet1" name="diet" value="0">Low sugar
                <input type="radio" id="diet1" name="diet" value="0">Normal sugar 
                <input type="radio" id="diet1" name="diet" value="7">Quite high sugar
                <input type="radio" id="diet1" name="diet" value="10">High sugar
            </label>
        </div>  
        <div class="button">
            <input id="btn" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="CalculateValue()"> 
        <!--    <input id="submit" type"submit" value="submit"> -->
        </div>
    </fieldset>         
</form> 
<div id="lRisk">
    <h2> Your Result </h2>
    <p> Your results show that you currently have a low risk of developing diabetes.     However, it is important that you maintain a healty lifestyle in terms of diet and exercise. </p>
</div>
<div id="mRisk">
    <h2> Your Result </h2>
    <p> Your results show that you currently have a medium risk of developing diabetes. For more information on your risk factors, and what to do about them, please visit our diabetes advice website at <a href="http://www.zha.org.zd">http://www.zha.org.zd.</a> </p>
</div>       
<div id="hRisk">
    <h2> Your Result </h2>
    <p>Your results show that you currently have a HIGH risk of developing diabetes.<span id="space"></span> We advice that you contact the Health Authority to discuss your risk factors as soon as you can. Please fill in our <a href="index2.html"> contact form</a> and a member of the Health Authority Diabetes Team will be in contact with you. </p>
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: I also checked the [http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/] DOM CORE and it doesn't look to be any issues with the elements that I've used.

Comment: have you tried running [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) on it?

Comment: Fixed. Like fuximus goe said "removing the the changeCSS functions and just executing their code straight away fixes the problem", solved the browser compatibilliy issues.

Answer (score 0):

Only modification that I had to do is delete the function changeCSS() and just add what was inside in the if statement.

Thanks Fuximus Foe.

JSCode is here.

```
 function getAgeValue()
{
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('age').length; i++)
{
    if (document.getElementsByName('age')[i].checked)
    {
        return document.getElementsByName('age')[i].value;
    }
}
}

function getBmiValue()
{
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('bmi').length; i++)
{
    if (document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].checked)
    {
        return document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].value;
    }
}
}    


function getFamValue()
{
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('fam').length; i++)
{
    if (document.getElementsByName('fam')[i].checked)
    {
        return document.getElementsByName('fam')[i].value;
    }
}   
}

function getDietValue()
{
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('diet').length; i++)
{
    if (document.getElementsByName('diet')[i].checked)
    {
        return document.getElementsByName('diet')[i].value;
    }
}      
}

function CalculateValue()  {
var age = +getAgeValue('age'),
    bmi = +getBmiValue('bmi'),
    fami = +getFamValue('fam'),
    diet = +getDietValue('diet'),
    totalBMI = age + bmi + fami + diet;
    totalBMI = parseFloat(totalBMI); 
    alert(totalBMI);
if (totalBMI > 26) {           
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        var hMessage = document.getElementById("hRisk");
        hMessage.style.display = 'inline';
        /*var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        var newSpanText = document.createTextNode("Your main factors risk are "  );
        newSpan.appendChild(newSpanText);
        var pElem = document.getElementById("space");
        pElem.appendChild(newSpan); */
        }         
} else if (totalBMI > 16 ) {
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        var mMessage = document.getElementById("mRisk");
        mMessage.style.display = 'inline';
        } 
} else {
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        var lMessage = document.getElementById("lRisk");
        lMessage.style.display = 'inline';
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not closed any `input` tags consider using `<input ... />` self closing tags. You have misplaced closing `</label>` tags.

You shouldn't redeclare a function just to use on the next line.
Not sure, why you're binding to `onclick` event when you already have the answer, that makes it work only when the user hits the `calculate` button twice.

After fiddling around with this, removing the the changeCSS functions and just executing their code straight away fixes the problem. This is because in Chrome is grabbing the first definition of the function regardless whether the cursor reaches it or not, thus executing only the first changeCSS function on all three cases; firefox reads the correct definition.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    function CalculateValue() {
    var totalBMI = 0+parseInt(getAgeValue('age'))
            +parseInt(getBmiValue('bmi'))
            +parseInt(getFamValue('fam'))
            +parseInt(getDietValue('diet'));
    alert(totalBMI);
    if (totalBMI > 26) {
        //function changeCSS(){
            //document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
                var hMessage = document.getElementById("hRisk");
                hMessage.style.display = 'block';
                /*var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
                var newSpanText = document.createTextNode("Your main factors risk are "  );
                newSpan.appendChild(newSpanText);
                var pElem = document.getElementById("space");
                pElem.appendChild(newSpan); */
            //}
        //}
        //changeCSS();
    } else if (totalBMI > 16) {
        //function changeCSS(){
            //document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
                var mMessage = document.getElementById("mRisk");
                mMessage.style.display = 'block';
            //}
        //}
        //changeCSS();
    } else {
        //function changeCSS(){
            //document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
                var lMessage = document.getElementById("lRisk");
                lMessage.style.display = 'block';
            //}
        //}
        //changeCSS();
    }
}



function getAgeValue() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('age').length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName('age')[i].checked) {
            return document.getElementsByName('age')[i].value;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

function getBmiValue() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('bmi').length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].checked) {
            return document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].value;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


function getFamValue() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('fam').length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName('fam')[i].checked) {
            return document.getElementsByName('fam')[i].value;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

function getDietValue() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('diet').length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName('diet')[i].checked) {
            return document.getElementsByName('diet')[i].value;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="process.php" id="radioForm">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label for="age" class="lClass"><span class="span1"> How old are you?</span></label> 
                <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="0"/>0-25
                <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="5"/>26-40
                <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="8"/>41-60
                <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="10"/>60+
            </div>
        <div>   
            <label for="bmi"> <span class="span1"> What is your BMI? </span></label>
                <input type="radio" id="bmi1" name="bmi" value="0"/>0-25
                <input type="radio" id="bmi1" name="bmi" value="0"/>26-30
                <input type="radio" id="bmi1" name="bmi" value="9"/>31-35
                <input type="radio" id="bmi1" name="bmi" value="10"/>35+
        </div>
        <div>   
            <label for="fam"> <span class="span1"> Does anybody in your family have diabetes?</span></label>
                <input type="radio" id="fam1" name="fam" value="0"/>No
                <input type="radio" id="fam1" name="fam" value="7"/>Grandparent
                <input type="radio" id="fam1" name="fam" value="15"/>Sibling
                <input type="radio" id="fam1" name="fam" value="15"/>Parent
        </div>
        <div>   
            <label for="diet"> <span class="span1"> How would you describe your diet? </span></label>
            <input type="radio" id="diet1" name="diet" value="0"/>Low sugar
            <input type="radio" id="diet1" name="diet" value="0"/>Normal sugar 
            <input type="radio" id="diet1" name="diet" value="7"/>Quite high sugar
            <input type="radio" id="diet1" name="diet" value="10"/>High sugar
        </div>  
        <div class="button">
            <input id="btn" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="CalculateValue()"/> 
        <!--    <input id="submit" type"submit" value="submit"> -->
        </div>
    </fieldset>         
</form> 
<div id="lRisk" style="display:none;">
    <h2> Your Result </h2>
    <p> Your results show that you currently have a low risk of developing diabetes.     However, it is important that you maintain a healty lifestyle in terms of diet and exercise. </p>
</div>
<div id="mRisk" style="display:none;">
    <h2> Your Result </h2>
    <p> Your results show that you currently have a medium risk of developing diabetes. For more information on your risk factors, and what to do about them, please visit our diabetes advice website at <a href="http://www.zha.org.zd">http://www.zha.org.zd.</a> </p>
</div>       
<div id="hRisk" style="display:none;">
    <h2> Your Result </h2>
    <p>Your results show that you currently have a HIGH risk of developing diabetes.<span id="space"></span> We advice that you contact the Health Authority to discuss your risk factors as soon as you can. Please fill in our <a href="index2.html"> contact form</a> and a member of the Health Authority Diabetes Team will be in contact with you. </p>
</div>  
</body>
```

and the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kWyx8/

Comment: The end tag for `<input>` is forbidden. Being able to put a `/` at the end is a bit of nonsense syntactic sugar for people addicted to XML. It isn't a solution to any problem that doesn't involve a yellow screen of death or an XML parser shouting about a well formedness error.

Comment: The unary plus operator casts a value to a number.

Comment: yea, i figured @Quentin, I'm just used to these syntaxes, my fault.
the + sign on the other hand looks and feels dirty. even though it works.